# DB-API Type_Codes for Google Cloud Sql: Different from MySQLdb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

I'm finding that the type_codes returned by cursor.description from DB-API are different for Google Cloud SQL than a standard MySQLdb implementation.  For example: in [MySQLdb (mysqldb-python)](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE-module.html), VAR_STRING is 253, and NEWDECIMAL is 246.  However, when I try to get these values from Google Cloud SQL (from Google App Engine, using the Python "rdbms" package), I get different values: VAR_STRING = 12 and NEWDECIMAL is 3.

1) Does anyone know where I can find the proper type_code mappings for Google Cloud SQL?

2) Even better, standard MySQLdb (mysqldb-python) implementations have [constants](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE-module.html) that I can use directly in my python code.  Are these available anywhere for the python libraries for Google Cloud SQL (i.e. "rdbms")?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use MySQLdb with Google Cloud SQL, so there's no need to use the rdbms API anymore.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_complete_python_example

Hope this helps,

Rob